# VirtualBox:Got multi arp replies when ping the virtual nic in guest OS

Tags: virtualbox, arp

I have met a problem with virtualbox, I hope someone could help me here, I'll very preciate about it:
My host OS is Ubuntu 9.10, the guest OS is RouterOS, Virtualbox version is 4.10, I virtualize two wired interface in RouterOS, which is 192.168.202.254 and 192.168.202.253, however, when I send a arp request to 192.168.202.254,I also got a APR reply from .253.
The same thing happens when I send a arp request to 253. See the picture below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykmLf.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid this is caused by the guest os ---- RouterOS
I'v changed the version of RouterOS,and it worked fine